# DBAL Symfony 2 SQL Statements

Tags: php, symfony, dbal

I'm currently playing around with symfony and DBAL to collect data from an external database.

```
        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');

        $users = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM cms_clients');

        print_r($users);
```

The code above works fine, but I need to do more complicated queries, and the only documentation I can find is http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

The documentation is really good but i'm not sure how i would implement the code bellow in my example.

`$queryBuilder
    ->select('u.id', 'u.name')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->where('u.email = ?')
    ->setParameter(0, $userInputEmail)
;`

**Solution, thanks for replays anyway**

> ```
>       $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
> ```

```
        $parms = array($DataSource, 'STORE');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM cms_things LEFT JOIN cms_stores ON cms_things.id=cms_stores.thing_id WHERE client_id = ? AND type = ? ";

        $users = $conn->fetchAll($query, $parms);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thing like this may help

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$params = array('state' => 'active');
$qb->select("DISTINCT (a.id) as url , a.name , a.pages , a.section , a.clickable")
        ->from('Tbl', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.country', 'cnt')
        ->where('a.state=:state')
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
$qb->setParameters($params);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$list = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::getQuery() in

Comment: you can find     public function getQuery()

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php

Comment: maybe different version of doctrine ... what's your version?

Comment: $parms = array($DataSource, 'STORE');
                                         
      
      
              /* LEFT JOIN cms_stores ON cms_things.id=cms_stores.thing_id WHERE client_id  */
                                          
      $query = "SELECT * FROM cms_things LEFT JOIN cms_stores ON cms_things.id=cms_stores.thing_id WHERE client_id = ? AND type = ? ";